Why CSS grid extends to viewdith?
I have a tic-tac-toe game representend by a CSS Grid.
If I go with "fixed" units for the columns, e.g. px or vw, the grid "extends" to the view width as shown below via the black border. My current understanding or expectation would be that the grid would only extend to the width of the 3 columns, so around 300 pixels if there is no margin, padding, or border.


.tictactoe-board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  border: 1px solid black;
}


.tictactoe-case {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height : 100px;
}

.tictactoe-case:hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 60%;

}

.tictactoe-coin {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}
<div class="tictactoe-board">
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case1">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case2">
       <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case3">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case4">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case5">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case6">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case7">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case8">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case9">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
  </div>



If I instead use fr units, then the grid obviously "stops" at the 3 columns given they take up all space. What am I missing?


.tictactoe-board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  border: 1px solid black;
}


.tictactoe-case {
  background-color: red;
  height : 100px;
}

.tictactoe-case:hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 60%;

}

.tictactoe-coin {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}
<div class="tictactoe-board">
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case1">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case2">
       <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case3">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case4">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case5">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case6">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case7">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case8">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tictactoe-case" id="tictactoe-case9">
      <div class="tictactoe-coin"></div>
    </div>
  </div>




display: grid alone means that the element will be full width of its parent regardless of what you define inside it. What you want is inline-grid

You may also use .tictactoe-board{max-width:max-content;} so it remains acting as a  block element
